# How can I print these reversed pyramid next to each other?

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

I want to to display this reversed pyramid next to each other but the problem is the right side of my pyramid is different in the left side of my pyramid. How can I fix this? [image: Here is the lopsided image] and
[image: this is what it should look like].

```
package proj;

public class Looping {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        for (int r=5; r>0; r--) {
            
            for (int s=5-r; s>0; s--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int k=2*r-1; k>0; k--) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            for (int s=5-r; s>0; s--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int k=2*r-1; k>0; k--) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: The best way to solve this is to imagine that the pyramids are in a "frame" and fill up all the characters. I.e. you either print a space or an asterisk *for each position* in the frame. Currently you are not printing the *trailing* spaces of the first pyramid.

Comment: Your loops add whitespace to the left side of each pyramid, but not to the right side.  This works for the rightmost pyramid, because nothing comes "after" it on each line, but padding in the left pyramid is critical for the alignment of the right pyramid.

Answer (score 3):

### [`String#repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int))

You can do it using a single loop using [`String#repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)).

**Demo**:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int ROWS = 5;
        for (int i = 1; i <= ROWS; i++) {
            String stars = "*".repeat((ROWS + 1) * 2 - 2 * i - 1);
            System.out.println(" ".repeat(i - 1) + stars + " ".repeat(i * 2 - 1) + stars);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
********* *********
 *******   *******
  *****     *****
   ***       ***
    *         *
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this is to imagine that the pyramids are in a "frame" and fill up all the characters. I.e. you either print a space or an asterisk *for each position* in the frame. Currently you are not printing the *trailing* spaces of the first pyramid, which means that each following pyramid will be increasingly lopsided.

The way I would write it is to have a double `for` loop for the X and a Y coordinates, and then have a function to tell me if the current X and Y fall within a specific pyramid (one call for each pyramid). This also allows for other patterns to be printed. See it as a simple form of ray tracing.

```
for (int y = 0; y < 22; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
        if (inPyramid(0, 0, x, y) || inPyramid(10, 0, x, y)) {
            System.out.print("*");
        else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

with the following method:

```
public boolean inPyramid(int pyramidOffsetX, int pyramidOffsetY, int x, int y) {
    // TODO fill in the tricky part :)
}
```

This seems a bit harder, but it will easily allow overlap of shapes and such, and it is a much more structured approach.

Answer (score -1):

In order to draw upside-down pyramids next to each other, you will need to know the amount of pyramids and the size of the pyramid.

This is an O(n³) complexity algorithm (triple-nested loop).

```java
public class Pyramids {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(render(2, 9)); // 2 pyramids with a base of 9
        System.out.println(render(4, 5)); // 4 pyramids with a base of 5
    }
    
    public static String render(int count, int size) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        int rows = (int) Math.floor(size / 2) + 1;
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            for (int pyramid = 0; pyramid < count; pyramid++) {
                int indentSize = pyramid == 0 ? row : row * 2;
                for (int indent = 0; indent < indentSize; indent++) {
                    buffer.append(" "); // indent
                }
                int starCount = size - (row * 2);
                for (int star = 0; star < starCount; star++) {
                    buffer.append("*"); // star
                }
                buffer.append("  ");;  // separator
            }
            buffer.append(System.lineSeparator());  // new-line
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

### Output

```
*********  *********  
 *******    *******  
  *****      *****  
   ***        ***  
    *          *  
*****  *****  *****  *****  
 ***    ***    ***    ***  
  *      *      *      *
```

---

Here is a JavaScript version of the Java code above.

```js
const renderPyramids = (count, size) => {
  let str = '';
  const rows = Math.floor(size / 2) + 1;
  for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (let pyramid = 0; pyramid < count; pyramid++) {
      const indentSize = pyramid === 0 ? row : row * 2;
      for (let indent = 0; indent < indentSize; indent++) {
        str += ' '; // indent
      }
      const starCount = size - (row * 2);
      for (let star = 0; star < starCount; star++) {
        str += '*'; // star
      }
      str += '  ';  // separator
    }
    str += '\n';  // new-line
  }
  return str;
};

console.log(renderPyramids(2, 9));
console.log(renderPyramids(4, 5));
```

Comment: This seems an OK approach but 1. you don't explain it at all, 2. you're using a different languages without telling and 3. you've solved the entire problem instead of showing how it can be done. Could you edit the answer and fix at least 1 & 2?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes oops, thought I was browsing the JS tag...